# Making tikz draw go almost all the way

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have by looking at examples at this site got quite far with tikz but not all the way. I know this might be considered a bad question -- but since I got this far by looking at similar question this is probably the best we can do when it comes to tikz -- but here comes what I have now:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix(Person) [matrix of nodes, 
                 matrix/.style={rows={1}{fill=gray}},
                 label=above:Person, 
                 column 1/.style={nodes={text width=1cm, align=center}},
                 column 2/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
                 column 3/.style={nodes={text width=2.5cm}},
                 column 4/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
                 column 5/.style={nodes={text width=2cm, align=center}}
                  ] {
    id & name       & address       & birth date & occupation.id \\
    1  & Mary Smith & Main street 1 & 1970-04-17 & 1 \\
    2  & John Doe   & Highway 2     & 1972-07-24 & 1 \\ 
    3  & Clara Doe  & Highway 2     & 1995-11-11 & 2 \\};

\matrix(Child) [matrix of nodes, 
                label=above:Child, 
                nodes={text width=2cm, align=center}, 
                right=1 cm of Person] {
    Person.id & Person.id \\ 
    2 & 3                 \\
                          \\};

\matrix(Occupation) [matrix of nodes, 
                     label=above:Occupation, 
                     below=1.25cm of Person,
                     nodes={text width=2.5cm},
                     column 1/.style={nodes={text width=1cm, align=center}}] {
    id & title     & location \\
    1  & secretary & Enterprises ltd \\
    2  & student   & School \\};

\draw[thick](Person-1-1.north west)--(Person-1-5.north east);
\draw(Person-1-1.south west)--(Person-1-5.south east);
\draw[thick](Person-4-1.south west)--(Person-4-5.south east);

\draw[thick](Child-1-1.north west)--(Child-1-2.north east);
\draw(Child-1-1.south west)--(Child-1-2.south east);
\draw[thick](Child-2-1.south west)--(Child-2-2.south east);

\draw[thick](Occupation-1-1.north west)--(Occupation-1-3.north east);
\draw(Occupation-1-1.south west)--(Occupation-1-3.south east);
\draw[thick](Occupation-3-1.south west)--(Occupation-3-3.south east);

\draw[<->] (Child-1-1.north)--++(0,1.5)-|(Person-1-1.north);
\draw[<->] (Child-1-2.north)--++(0,1.75)-|(Person-1-1.north);
\draw[<->] (Occupation-1-1.north)--++(0,1)-|(Person-4-5.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I posted all of it cause it\s not that much and perhaps you while fixing what I can't fix also can show other better ways of doing what I have done -- both so I can learn and other people stumbling on this page also can learn.

Now, my problem is that I don't think it's clear enough what is table and what is not table. I think if the arrows didn't actually touch the table lines then perhaps it would become more clear. But I haven't so far managed to understand how to fix that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. To detach the arrows from the tables, you can use the `shorten >= length`
   , and `shorten <= length` keys.
2. You can also change the line width and/or the color for the arrows. In my example code I used the `help lines` style.
3. If you take a close look at your current tables, some of the lines are not completely horizontal due to different height and depth of the node contents; to guarantee equal dimensions (that will produce perfectly horizontal lines), you can set `text depth` and `text height` for the matrix nodes, or you could also use the perpendicular coordinate system to draw the lines. In my example I opted for the first option.

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix(Person) [matrix of nodes,
                 nodes={text depth=0.5ex,text height=2ex}, 
                 matrix/.style={rows={1}{fill=gray}},
                 label=above:Person, 
                 column 1/.style={nodes={text width=1cm, align=center}},
                 column 2/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
                 column 3/.style={nodes={text width=2.5cm}},
                 column 4/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
                 column 5/.style={nodes={text width=2cm, align=center}}
                  ] {
    id & name       & address       & birth date & occupation.id \\
    1  & Mary Smith & Main street 1 & 1970-04-17 & 1 \\
    2  & John Doe   & Highway 2     & 1972-07-24 & 1 \\ 
    3  & Clara Doe  & Highway 2     & 1995-11-11 & 2 \\};

\matrix(Child) [matrix of nodes, 
                label=above:Child, 
                nodes={text width=2cm, align=center}, 
                right=1 cm of Person] {
    Person.id & Person.id \\ 
    2 & 3                 \\
                          \\};

\matrix(Occupation) [matrix of nodes, 
                     label=above:Occupation, 
                     below=1.25cm of Person,
                     nodes={text width=2.5cm},
                     column 1/.style={nodes={text width=1cm, align=center}}] {
    id & title     & location \\
    1  & secretary & Enterprises ltd \\
    2  & student   & School \\};

\draw[thick](Person-1-1.north west)--(Person-1-5.north east);
\draw(Person-1-1.south west)--(Person-1-5.south east);
\draw[thick](Person-4-1.south west)--(Person-4-5.south east);

\draw[thick](Child-1-1.north west)--(Child-1-2.north east);
\draw(Child-1-1.south west)--(Child-1-2.south east);
\draw[thick](Child-2-1.south west)--(Child-2-2.south east);

\draw[thick](Occupation-1-1.north west)--(Occupation-1-3.north east);
\draw(Occupation-1-1.south west)--(Occupation-1-3.south east);
\draw[thick](Occupation-3-1.south west)--(Occupation-3-3.south east);

\begin{scope}[shorten >= 5pt,shorten <= 5pt,help lines,>=latex]
\draw[<->] (Child-1-1.north)--++(0,1.5)-|(Person-1-1.north);
\draw[<->] (Child-1-2.north)--++(0,1.75)-|(Person-1-1.north);
\draw[<->] (Occupation-1-1.north)--++(0,1)-|(Person-4-5.south);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

And adding `rounded corners` to the arrows might also improve the result:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix(Person) [matrix of nodes,
                 nodes={text depth=0.5ex,text height=2ex}, 
                 matrix/.style={rows={1}{fill=gray}},
                 label=above:Person, 
                 column 1/.style={nodes={text width=1cm, align=center}},
                 column 2/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
                 column 3/.style={nodes={text width=2.5cm}},
                 column 4/.style={nodes={text width=2cm}},
                 column 5/.style={nodes={text width=2cm, align=center}}
                  ] {
    id & name       & address       & birth date & occupation.id \\
    1  & Mary Smith & Main street 1 & 1970-04-17 & 1 \\
    2  & John Doe   & Highway 2     & 1972-07-24 & 1 \\ 
    3  & Clara Doe  & Highway 2     & 1995-11-11 & 2 \\};

\matrix(Child) [matrix of nodes, 
                label=above:Child, 
                nodes={text width=2cm, align=center}, 
                right=1 cm of Person] {
    Person.id & Person.id \\ 
    2 & 3                 \\
                          \\};

\matrix(Occupation) [matrix of nodes, 
                     label=above:Occupation, 
                     below=1.25cm of Person,
                     nodes={text width=2.5cm},
                     column 1/.style={nodes={text width=1cm, align=center}}] {
    id & title     & location \\
    1  & secretary & Enterprises ltd \\
    2  & student   & School \\};

\draw[thick](Person-1-1.north west)--(Person-1-5.north east);
\draw(Person-1-1.south west)--(Person-1-5.south east);
\draw[thick](Person-4-1.south west)--(Person-4-5.south east);

\draw[thick](Child-1-1.north west)--(Child-1-2.north east);
\draw(Child-1-1.south west)--(Child-1-2.south east);
\draw[thick](Child-2-1.south west)--(Child-2-2.south east);

\draw[thick](Occupation-1-1.north west)--(Occupation-1-3.north east);
\draw(Occupation-1-1.south west)--(Occupation-1-3.south east);
\draw[thick](Occupation-3-1.south west)--(Occupation-3-3.south east);

\begin{scope}[shorten >= 5pt,shorten <= 5pt,help lines,>=latex,rounded corners]
\draw[<->] (Child-1-1.north)--++(0,1.5)-|(Person-1-1.north);
\draw[<->] (Child-1-2.north)--++(0,1.75)-|(Person-1-1.north);
\draw[<->] (Occupation-1-1.north)--++(0,1)-|(Person-4-5.south);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]